# Last day of quarter

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to natively select the last day of each quarter in PySpark? For example, in a `df` containing two columns - `yyyy_mm_dd` and `sum`. How could I return `sum` for the last day of each quarter? For the current / in progress quarter it would be good to show the max date instead.

I looked at this solution [Get First Date and Last Date of Current Quarter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135699/get-first-date-and-last-date-of-current-quarter-in-python) and it works, however I was wondering if there is a solution using PySpark syntax rather than a udf?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821792/14165730

Comment: It helps a bit but seems to take the start date of the previous quarter whereas I need max date in current quarter. Similar to `.where(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd') == last day of q)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a similar approach as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821792/14165730):

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'last_day',
    F.expr("""
        to_date(
            date_trunc('quarter', to_date(input_date) + interval 3 months)
        ) - interval 1 day
    """)
)

df2.show()
+----------+----------+
|input_date|  last_day|
+----------+----------+
|2020-01-21|2020-03-31|
|2020-02-06|2020-03-31|
|2020-04-15|2020-06-30|
|2020-07-10|2020-09-30|
|2020-10-20|2020-12-31|
|2021-02-04|2021-03-31|
+----------+----------+
```

Then you can filter the rows where `input_date == last_day`

---

Edit: I might have misunderstood the question. You can try this approach using group by on the quarter and selecting the last row in each quarter:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(F.year('input_date'), F.quarter('input_date')).orderBy(F.desc('input_date')))
)

df2.show()
+----------+---+
|input_date| rn|
+----------+---+
|2021-02-04|  1|
|2020-10-20|  1|
|2020-07-10|  1|
|2020-02-06|  1|
|2020-01-21|  2|
|2020-04-15|  1|
+----------+---+
```

And filter the rows with `rn = 1`, which should be the last day in each quarter.

Comment: After filtering on `input_date == last_day` I think there would be no rows for incomplete quarters. though i still need to run it

Comment: I'm using Spark 2.2.0 so date_trunc() is actually unavailable unfortunately

Comment: @stackq see the edited answer? maybe it will do what you wanted

Comment: Run into an illegal character `q` error. But yes, maybe the original Q wasn't too clear. I'm essentially trying to do the equivalent of `select * from t where yyyy_mm_dd in ('2020-01-31', '2020-06-30', 2020-09-30', '2020-12-31', '2021-03-31' ....)` but without hardcoding dates

Comment: modified to be hopefully compatible with spark 2.2 ... I used `quarter` and `year`. please try again? @stackq

Answer (score 1):

You want to deduplicate and keep the max date that exists in each quarter. You can use [`trunc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trunc) with Window function :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy(F.trunc('date_col', 'quarter')).orderBy(F.col('date_col').desc())

df1 = df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w)) \
        .filter("rn = 1") \
        .drop("rn")
```

Comment: trunc doesn't support quarter?

Comment: @mck yes, it supports! why?

Comment: the docs you linked seem to suggest only year/month, and I tried quarter and I got null... not sure if it's a spark version problem though

Comment: @mck you're right! the function exists since 1.5 but support for quarter was added in Spark 3... [spark 3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#trunc) / [spark 2.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/#trunc). was looking at the wrong docs.